# alternate way of specifying string path to variable in C#

Tags: c#

Is there another way of assigning string path to variable aside from this:

```
strPath = @"C:\Myfile.txt";
```

- is there another way instead using "@" sign in the string path.

thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the `@` sign?

Comment: in my situation i try not to specify the string path (hard coded). the string path will come from an openfiledialog, i pass it like this
strPath = openfiledialog1.filename;
when i run the program the error message was "cannot access "myFile.xls". Well i try to open it using microsoft.office.interop.excel library i thought the problem was on the code in opening the excel but when i try to hardcode the path using the @ sign it works. any suggestions? "

Comment: The `@` sign has nothing to do with your problem; this question is irrelevant.  You should ask a separate question about the exception.

Answer (score 4):

You can escape it:

```
var myPath = "C:\\MyFile.txt"
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean another way of escaping the backslashes?

The @ sign at the start means that the string is treated as a verbatim string literal, and simple escape sequences such as \n or \t are ignored.

If you don't put the @ at the start it is not verbatim, and escape sequences are parsed.  If you want to ignore an individual escape sequence you can precede it with a single backslash and it will be ignored.

The reason you would use it in a path such as your example is so that you don't have to escape each individual backslash as you would if you didn't put the @ at the start:

```
strPath = "C:\\Myfile.txt";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use forward slashes and it'll work fine on Windows and no escaping needed.

```
strPath = "C:/Myfile.txt";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Unicode Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)....

```
 string strPath = "C:\u005CMyfile.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

string path = Path.Combine("C:", "myfile.txt");